# Add PersonEmail field to Account Related Record in Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-console

I have a Sales Console that display an Account info as related record. My question is can I add the PersonEmail field (specific field for record type "Person Account") to related record layout? I try to find in this layout editor but it's seem that all specific field for Person Account is not supported.
Anyone can help me?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to the below excerpt from the Page Layout section from this [help article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=account_person_behavior.htm&type=5), Person Accounts have their own page layouts. So as long as your Account info is of type Person Account, you can do it.

> Person accounts have their own page layouts that can include account and contact fields, account custom links, and account and contact related lists.

So in order to have the Person Account specific fields, you can follow the below steps to add these fields. Remember the *Person* prefix is just an API name, the actual fields on the Page Layout are reflected using their correct labels. 
E.g., *PersonEmail* is just *Email*. You can refer to more details on Person Account fields [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=account_fields.htm&type=5#PersonAccountFieldsTitle).

> Fields with a prefix “Person” or suffix “_pc” are contact fields that are supported for person accounts but not business accounts.

Steps to add Person Account fields on the "Person Account" page layout (in Lightning).

1. Go to Setup --> Object Manager
2. Navigate to "Person Account" (You will see there's a Person Account object available in there)
3. Select the Page Layout and make the necessary changes

   [image]

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK this is not possible at the moment. But please have a look (and upvote) [here](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000Gdj6wUAB/allow-person-account-fields-in-account-custom-update-actions) and/or [here](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000Gdcg9UAB/allow-inline-editing-of-person-accounts-in-related-record-lightning-component).

Comment: If there's some workarounds in those links, please reproduce them here. Salesforce has a fairly poor reputation for changing links on us, so reproducing the important bits here will keep this answer useful after they do that again.

Comment: I wrote that it is not possible at the moment. Which is an answer (although of course not one that is preferable). The links direct to the Ideas platform of Salesforce where many ideas are floating around for almost a decade.